# Moving character at the beginning of the string maintaining the position of other characters intact in R

Tags: r

```
string <- paste(append(rep(" ", 7), append("A", append(rep(" ", 3), append("B", append(rep(" ", 17), "C"))))), collapse = "")

string
[1] "       A   B                 C"
```

how can I move A at the beginning of the string, keeping the position of B and C the same?

Comment: What do you mean move? Replace A by a space and replace the first space by A?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `sub` to get all spaces `( *)` before a word `(\\w+)` and change their position `\\2\\1`.

```
sub("( *)(\\w+)", "\\2\\1", string)
#[1] "A          B                 C"
```

Or only for `A`:

```
sub("( *)A", "A\\1", string)
```